# Memory management on android -App won't load due to not enough memory on emulator

Tags: android

I'm trying to port over a tarot fortune card reading game from the iPhone to android.
I put all the unscaled images which took up about 19 mb.  I was under the assumption that androids usually have 512 mb of ram? Why would the app not load if its whole size is about 20mb?? I did scale down the images, so the memory dropped down to around 8mb and it loaded fine.

Does anybody know how the memory management works or a good link? I'm going to have some sound effects and more graphics.  Worried that the apk won't load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, each app is given a limited amount of memory to operate within. It usually varies from 16MB to 24MB, normally being lower on older devices. To avoid this, games often use OpenGL textures, as they do not count in this memory limit, IIRC. Additionally, allocating memory from the NDK circumvents this limit, but is not very convenient.

You could add android:largeHeap="true" to your  tag to get a larger amount of memory allocated to you, but it only works on 3.X and above, AFAIK.

Comment: Hi,Thank you, i goes 18mb was within the memory limitation

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just because an image takes up a little space in disk that does not mean it will use that same amount of memory when it's being displayed. To calculate how much memory an image will take (approximately), do `H x W x 4`. Then there's the limits imposed by android, which vary depending on the screen size (16 MB and higher, but not much more). In general, you can very few full screen images. Also, since your images are probably much larger than the phone's screen, you need to downsample them so they take less memory. There's a lot of info covering that subject right here in SO.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your comment, yes I did downsize them and it fix the problem, on another note the iphone version I did not bother to downsize the images. it worcked fine but yes I should have downsize them on the iphone to.